# UIActivityTypePostToFacebook howto post image and text xcode ios NSDictionary key for text

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, uiactivityviewcontroller

in My CustomActivityItemProvider I got this code for custom Facebook share items:

```
@implementation CustomActivityItemProvider

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *text;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSURL *url;
@property(nonatomic,strong) UIImage *image;

- (id)item {
            if ([self.activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMessage]) {
                return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",self.text,self.url];
                }

            if ([self.activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook]) {
                //>>>>FACEBOOK
                self.url = [NSUrl urlWithString:@"http://www.google.it"];
                self.text = @"FaceBookText";
                self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageShare.png"];
                NSDictionary *d = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[self.text,self.image,self.url] forKeys:@[@"text",@"image",@"url"]];
                return d;
                }
        return @"";
    }
```

I can't send image and text... I have try with all possible key: "title" or "text" or "description" but nothing.. I see the img, I see the url.. but I don't see any text... can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong ??

thanks you !

Comment: According to the facebook platform policy, prefill of any dialog is not allowed : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill

Comment: u'r not right. to create a message for fascebook, xcode use native method, and they allow to write text on system dialog. The strange think, as I wrote before, is that I can write text and put an image, but I can't put url and image... very strange !!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to subclass UIActivityItemProvider for each data type you wish to pass to UIActivityViewController. The reason you need each subclass of UIActivityItemProvider is for providing the specific data type when initializing your UIActivityItemProvider subclass with initWithPlaceholderItem:.

So in your example you would have a string and an image subclass of UIActivityItemProvider. The string subclass would return an empty string for its initWithPlaceholderItem:. The image subclass would return any image in your asset catalog for it's initWithPlaceholderItem:.

Also, although undocumented and totally annoying, the Facebook activity does not allow a string activity item provider if the Facebook app is installed. And even then it seems to strip out URL's and hashtags that you send to it.